# Google Charts: How to auto re-size inside panel?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using google charts and put them inside bootstrap panel. How can I make the charts re-size when the panel resizes? Sometimes they look okay on a particular resolution and sometimes display is cut off.

[image]

Gets cutoff when i zoom in:
[image]

My cshtml:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="font-weight:900">CHART #1
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="stakeholder-chart"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my JS for the chart options:

```
width: 500,
 height: 400,
```

Answer (score 2):

Were looking around for a solution myself, and found [Flo Preyant's example](http://codepen.io/flopreynat/pen/BfLkA). I can copy his CodePen into an answer, but you should see it for yourself and credits goes to him.

It's not Bootstrap (or BS Panel) specific, but it's responsive with regards to browser width.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-1-2">
    <div id="chart_div1" class="chart"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-2">
    <div id="chart_div2" class="chart"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
* {
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}

$pad: 20px;

.grid {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 0 $pad 0;

  &:after {
    /* Or @extend clearfix */
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
  padding-right: $pad;
  .grid &:last-of-type {
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}
.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.col-1-2 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-1-4 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-1-8 {
  width: 12.5%;
}

/* Opt-in outside padding */
.grid-pad {
  padding: $pad 0 $pad $pad;
  [class*='col-']:last-of-type {
    padding-right: $pad;
  }
}
.chart {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 600px;
}
```

And his charts in JavaScript:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);
function drawChart1() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2004',  1000,      400],
    ['2005',  1170,      460],
    ['2006',  660,       1120],
    ['2007',  1030,      540]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
 };

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);
function drawChart2() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2013',  1000,      400],
    ['2014',  1170,      460],
    ['2015',  660,       1120],
    ['2016',  1030,      540]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
    vAxis: {minValue: 0}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

$(window).resize(function(){
  drawChart1();
  drawChart2();
});

// Reminder: you need to put https://www.google.com/jsapi in the head of your document or as an external resource on codepen //
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add chartArea option to your JS options, something like that for example:

```
chartArea: {
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
        },
```

Or if you use some padding just reduce those a bit.